# SQL Server not alerting when deleting a field which is part of a view

Tags: sql-server

I just don´t understand why SQL Server doesn´t throw an error when you delete a column from a table, and that column is read by a View. To my understanding, SQL Server has that information, knows which columns/tables are read when you do a select query from a view, so i think it shoulnd´t let you delete a column referenced from a view, just like it doesn´t allow you to remove a column referenced by a FK...
There has to be an explanation to this, please someone tell me!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have to ask SQL Server to do this tracking. The option is called [SCHEMABINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition

The same option is also available on user defined functions, but unfortunately not on stored procedures.

It's not set by default - it's possible to construct a view that resolves its tables to different base tables for different users (assuming the users have different default schemas)

Comment: Always use SCHEMABINDING. Makes life easier (albeit with some minor development overhead)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that was exactly what i was looking for. Is it possible to set this option by default, so that every time i create a view in the future it has SCHEMABINDING ON? I can´t find that option in the SQL Server Management Studio...

Comment: @molerus - If you're using some kind of designer, I'm not sure - I write my queries by hand (and so, of course, have to include `SCHEMABINDING` myself). If you use the visual studio templates, I believe that they're editable (again, I don't use them myself)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the views. Here is a script that refresh all the view on a database:

```
DECLARE @ViewName AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @tblErrorViews TABLE(ViewName VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE listOfView CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Name] FROM sysobjects 
    WHERE xtype = 'V'
    AND uid = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')

OPEN listOfView

FETCH NEXT FROM listOfView into @ViewName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM listOfView INTO @ViewName
            print @ViewName
            EXEC sp_refreshview @ViewName
    END

CLOSE listOfView
DEALLOCATE listOfView
```

The you will know which view that needs your attention

Comment: That's how to find out which views have been impacted by a change, not preventing the change from occurring if it will affect any view

Comment: Yes that's true. But if you know that you have delete a column (that I rarely do). Then you can just run the script and see if any views have an impact on that change.